# Text bombardment

Tags: c#

this is the program I'm trying to write:

> Write a program that reads a text and line width from the console. The program should distribute the text so that it fits in a table with a specific line width. Each cell should contain only 1 character. It should then read a line with numbers, holding the columns that should be bombarded.

My code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _04.Text_Bombardment
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sentence = Console.ReadLine();
            var bombing = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            var selected = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
            Dictionary<int, bool> bombDict = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
            var newSentence = sentence + new string(' ', bombing - sentence.Length % bombing); // whole row minus words left

            for (int i = 0; i < selected.Length; i++)
            {
                bombDict.Add(selected[i], true);
            }
            var rows = newSentence.Length / bombing;
            var cols = bombing;

            var count = 0;

            var arrSent = newSentence.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    if (bombDict.ContainsKey(j) && bombDict[j] == true && arrSent[count] != ' ')
                    {
                        arrSent[count] = ' ';
                        try
                        {
                            if (arrSent[count + bombing] == ' ')
                            {
                                bombDict[j] = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                bombDict[j] = true;
                            }

                        }
                        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                   }
                   count++;
                }
            }
            var finalSent = string.Join("", arrSent).TrimEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(finalSent);
       }
   }
}
```

And it breaks on this sentence:

```
Vazov received his elementary education in hisnative town of Sopoandat Plovdiv. The son of a conservative, well-to-do merchant.
20
1 6 17 2 5 0 15
```

Current Output:

```
ov  eceived  i  e   en  ry educa i n    hi  ative to n of  opo  dat Plov iv. T e s   of a co serva ive  well-to- o mer ha t.
```

Intended Output:

```
ov  eceived  i  e   en  ry educa i n    hi  ative to n of  opo  dat Plov iv. T e s   of a co serva ive  well-to- o mer han .
```

Soo it only doesn't work on the end.
Can someone help me?
Any suggestions?

---

Additional notes:

<sup>For example, we read the text "Well this problem is gonna be a ride." and line width 10. We distribute the text among 4 rows with 10 columns. We read the numbers "1 3 7 9" and drop bombs on those columns in the table.
The bombs destroy the character they fall on + all the neighbouring characters below it. 

Note: Empty spaces below destroyed characters stop the bombs (see column 7).
Finally, we print the bombarded text on the console:      "W l  th s p o lem i   o na be a r de."
Note: The empty cells in the table after the text should NOT be printed.</sup>
[image]

Comment: What is the *exact* problem with the code you're having? Why doesn't the `b` get destroyed in the image?

Comment: @Sayse "Note: Empty spaces below destroyed characters stop the bombs "

Comment: @Sayse: »Note: Empty spaces below destroyed characters stop the bombs (see column 7)«. Reading helps. In any case, this sounds a lot like a homework assignment.

Comment: Your indexing to you arrays are off.  Your two for loops assume that is data is exactly rows * cols, but your string is not exactly the same size.  If you input string is 44 characters and you have 5 rows and 10 columns then you are going to get an error when you try to read the 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, and 50 character from the string.

Comment: I see where's the problem but how can I fix it?

Comment: in the images that you posted, the b in the 3rd word should be marked as *(bomb) and it is not! so it's wrong. So the final sentence of the example is: W l  th s p o lem i   o na  e a r de.

Comment: @user1845593 It looks like you meant third line not third word? Then no, the rules say "Empty spaces below destroyed characters stop the bombs (see column 7)." See the first three comments here on the question.

Comment: Thanks @Rup, you're right! So "Martin Dimitrov" you have to modify my answer below, but I think is a great help anyways. I kept the code simple and with the same style as yours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is very difficult to understand, keep it simple give names to the variables that you can understand easily.

I modified your code, hope it helps you:

```
static void Main()
{
    string sentence = "Well this problem is gonna be a ride.";
    int numberOfColumns = int.Parse("10");
    List<int> bombs = "1 3 7 9".Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToList();


    // we need to convert to decimal, otherwise C# will ignore decimal part. 
    //example: 127/20 = 6.35, so we need 7 rows. if we don't convert to decimal we have 6
    // the Ceiling says, always round up. so even 6.1 will be rounded to 7
    int numberOfRows = (int)Math.Ceiling(sentence.Length / Convert.ToDecimal(numberOfColumns));

    char[,] array = new char[numberOfRows, numberOfColumns];

    int sentencePointer = 0;
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numberOfRows; rowIndex++)
    {
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < numberOfColumns; colIndex++)
        {
            // if you want to print the grid with the full text, just comment the 3 lines below,
            //and keep only "array[rowIndex, colIndex] = sentence[sentencePointer];"
            if (bombs.Contains(colIndex))
            {
                if (sentence[sentencePointer] == ' ') // bomb is deactivated
                {
                    bombs.Remove(colIndex);
                    array[rowIndex, colIndex] = sentence[sentencePointer];
                }
                else
                    array[rowIndex, colIndex] = '*'; // * represents a bomb
            }
            else
                array[rowIndex, colIndex] = sentence[sentencePointer];

            sentencePointer++; // move next character
            if (sentencePointer >= sentence.Length)
                break; // we reach the end of the sentence.
        }
    }

    PrintGrid(array, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns);

    // just give some space to print the final sentence
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("");

    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numberOfRows; rowIndex++)
    {
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < numberOfColumns; colIndex++)
        {
            Console.Write(array[rowIndex, colIndex]);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void PrintGrid(char[,] array, int numberOfRows, int numberOfColumns)
{
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', numberOfColumns * 2));

    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numberOfRows; rowIndex++)
    {
        Console.Write("|");
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < numberOfColumns; colIndex++)
        {
            Console.Write(array[rowIndex, colIndex]);
            Console.Write("|");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you forget to check for this rule: "Note: The empty cells in the table after the text should NOT be printed." There's an empty cell below the letter on the second row, third column array[1, 2] which should stop the letters below it from being bombarded but it doesn't. Therefore the sentence at the end is again wrong. That's why I was using a dictionary with a boolean variable attached to the index.

Comment: Yes you're right, as user @Rup as mention in the comments of your first post, I'm missing that rule. Basically you just need to add that logic. Change the if: `if (bombs.Contains(colIndex) && sentence[sentencePointer] != ' ')` to add that logic. The pseudo-code is: `if (bombs.Contains(colIndex) { if the char on the sentence is empty THEN remove the bombs ELSE array[rowIndex, colIndex] = '*'; }`

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines "if the cell below the bombed character is empty change a boolean value to false". Still, I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Check my solution now. now the output is the same as the images that you have. Anyways I won't update my answer anymore, you have more than enough information here, you should be able to debug and understand the program and change it

Comment: I solved it and kept the dictionary. Nevertheless, thank you very much for the help. All of the answers here helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat more elegant solution.

```
private static IEnumerable<char> Bomb(IEnumerable<char> text, IEnumerable<int> indexes, int length)
{
    var indexArray = new List<int>(indexes);
    var used = new object[length];

    return text.Select(
        (c, index) =>
            {
                if (c != ' ' && indexArray.Contains(index % length))
                {
                    used[index % length] = new object();
                    return '\0';
                }

                if (c == ' ' && used[index % length] != null)
                {
                    indexArray.Remove(index % length);
                }

                return c;
            });
}
```

Comment: You're using `index > length` to permit a bomb to drop through an empty square on the top row, but I think that will permit it dropping through only a single row whereas I'd interpret the rules as it can fall any number of rows until it hits the first letter. I think you'd need more state: has this index been used, and then if we hit a space after it's been used then we remove it. (I'm also not wild about mutating the input index list, but that can be documented away.)

Comment: Yes, you are correct in your observations. I'll update it :)